# Add Media Library Filter in WordPress to filter Media which are assigned to specific post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, media, wordpress-media

I have multiple post types in WordPress and related to that I want to filter media by post type. For an example I have PDF in form submissions where post type is "Submission", other post type is "Scripts", I want to filter media which are in "Submission" post type.

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this? Add your code to the question.